# Evaluating time elapsed between two actions in MIPS assembly language

Tags: mips

I am using the Mars tool and I need to write a program evaluate the time elapsed between to actions using MIPS assembly language . For example, the time of calculating a certain operation. I found in the syscalls that I could use $v0,30 to use system time but I have no idea how to use it ?

Comment: The syscall you mention returns a timestemp in milliseconds - what else do you need ?

Comment: @PaulR , thanks for the reply. If invoke $v0,30 then what get stored in $a0 ?

Comment: Look at the notes below the list of syscalls here: http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html - `a0` contains the low order 32 bits and `a1` contains the high order 32 bits, giving you a 64 bit system time in ms - call this before and afterwards and subtract the two values to get elapsed time.

Comment: @PaulR I used the following code 
li $v0,30
li $v0,1
syscall
but it returns 0 , why ?

Comment: Look carefully - you are overwriting `v0` with the second `li`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `syscall` #30 to get a 64 bit timestamp in `a0:a1`:

```
li $v0,30          ; get start timestamp in a0:a1
syscall
; save a0:a1 somewhere

; ... do stuff

li $v0,30          ; get end timestamp in a0:a1
syscall

; subtract begin timestamp from end timestamp to get elapsed time
```

Comment: Hey thanks, why do we use syscall after invoking $v0 ?

Comment: You're not "invoking" `v0` - `v0` is just a register and you're loading it with an immediate value (30). You then invoke `syscall`, which looks at the value in `v0` to determine what it is supposed to do.